# FLWOR XQuery in c# returns empty?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xquery, flwor

I am trying to use a Xquery FLOWR where statement in C#:

```
for $x in //div[@class="class1"] where $x//span="data1" return $x
```

to get some data from an xml file. (The reason for using FLOWR is to easily read the queries runtime from an external file)

for this I use the Saxon API:
http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnet/dotnetapi.html

The xml code looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <div class="class1">
 <div class="class2">
  <span class="class3">
   data1
  </span>
  <span class="class4">
   data2
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="class5">
  data3
 </div>
 <div class="class6">
  data4
 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class1">
 <div class="class2">
  <span class="class3">
   data5
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="class5">
  data6
 </div>
    </div>
</doc>
```

If I test this code using X-base it works like I expect and returns one of the two class1 classes; however both Saxon and xpathtester.com compile the Xquery without errors but return empty.
If I remove the optional where statement it behaves as expected. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is BaseX's [`CHOP` option](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#CHOP), which trims all whitespace at the ends of text nodes. When imported into BaseX with `CHOP` enabled (which is the default), you document looks as follows:

```
<doc>
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
      <span class="class3">data1</span>
      <span class="class4">data2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="class5">data3</div>
    <div class="class6">data4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
      <span class="class3">data5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="class5">data6</div>
  </div>
</doc>
```

Since the `=` operator is whitespace sensitive on strings, your `where` clause matches the text contents of the chopped document, but not the original one.

You can trim the whitespace inside your query instead, which works in all cases:

```
for $x in //div[@class = "class1"]
where $x//span/normalize-space() = "data1"
return $x
```